# How to separate header from content

Tags: css, html

My header is covering the top section of the content below it.

ex:

`_________________
| header         |
| ______________ |
||______________||
 |    content   |
 |______________|`

How would i be able to make it so the div for the header is separate from the div for the content.

end goal:

```
 _________________
| header         |
|                |
|________________|
 _______________
|              |
|    content   |
|______________|
```

Html(Put in the div for the header. content is just some pics and `<p>` tags.):

```
  <div class='nav'>
    <ul class='Menu'>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>     
    <h3 class='Name'>name</h3>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-style: italic;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.Menu
{
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 40%;
/*  padding-top: 5px; */
}
.Menu li{
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20%;
}

.Menu li a{
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Name {
  display: inline-block
}

.Menu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav h3 {
  padding-left: 250px;
  Color: #7A7A99;
}

.intro {
  background: url('http://www.amritray.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/foggy-photographs21.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-ie-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Probably, you have negative margins or absolute positioned elements. Just don't use that and it will be fine.

Comment: Can you please paste the HTML that results in `header` covering up the top of `content`?

Comment: am damn sure its either uncleared floats or position absolute

Comment: @Mr.Alien It could be `position: fixed;`, too :-)

Comment: @TylerH ahhh yes, I hate that position..

Comment: Bad CSS, you have all sorts of redundant properties there, you are using `display: inline-block;` with `float: right;`, also no position for `.intro` and you are using `top` `right` `bottom` and `left` properties etc

Comment: @TylerH Would love to see `position: sticky;` in action some day

Comment: But the prolblem is still there, if I remove the `postion: fixed;` on the `.nav` The header would just dissappear

Comment: @Mr.Alien Soon. Next version of FF at least will support it enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
{position:relative}
```

for both header and content div, instead of fixed.

Comment: How would I have both the header and nav now that there separate take up the whole page so the white border around it will be covered by the two images. When I had `Position:absolute;` They took up the whole page now that i've changed both it has a white border?

Comment: If the page has a white border then   set the body tag to have a margin of 0px  body{ margin:0px;}

Comment: @AbdullahiFarah Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand your question now. Do you mean they(nav and img) don't take up the whole page and have white space around it after using position: relative? If so, have you tried fixing their width as 100% and setting padding to 0px?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two divs the only way you could manage to make them overlap is if you have negative margins or elements that are positioned either absolute or fixed. Just don't uses those two things it should work out.

Here is a basic example: http://jsbin.com/zakolaca/1/edit